# Do `seekg()` and `seekp()` operate on characters or bytes?

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

[Page 393](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=We21AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=%22however,+if+you+must,+you+can+use+positioning%22&source=bl&ots=oh1Gc-xhcV&sig=ACfU3U1g7b6ueLtj7_EUA26iNrgFig1yKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCg-PlsPH-AhXngFYBHYusCP8Q6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22however%2C%20if%20you%20must%2C%20you%20can%20use%20positioning%22&f=false)  of *'Programming: Principles and Practice'* introduces `seekg()` and `seekp()` as follows:

> However, if you must, you can use positioning to select a specific place in a file for reading or writing. Basically, every file that is open for reading has a "read/get position" and every file that is open for writing has a "write/put position":
>
> [diagram]
>
> ```
> fstream fs {name};          // open for input and output
> if (!fs) error("can't open ", name);
>
> fs.seek(5);                 // move reading position to the 5 (the 6th character)
> char ch;
> fs >> ch;                   // read and increment reading position
> cout << "character[5] is " << ch << ' {' << int(ch) << "}\n";
>
> fs.seekp(1);                // move writing position to 1
> fs << 'y';                  // write and increment writing position
> ```

In the code snippet, "position" is expressed in terms of characters, e.g. position 5 is referred as the "6th character". This confused me because up until this point, we've thought of a file as a sequence of bytes, so I would have expected position to be expressed in terms of *bytes* (in the example above, I thought 5 was the position of the 6th byte of the file).

So, I tried to test it out by writing to position 1 of a file containing a single wide character:

**wide.txt**

```
௸
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {

    fstream fs {"wide.txt"};

    fs.seekp(1);
    fs << 'y';
    fs.close();

    return 0;

}
```

After running this code, **wide.txt** looks like this:

```
�y�
```

It seems that the charater 'y' was written to the 2nd byte of the program, not to the 2nd character, which would imply that position refers to a byte, not a character. **So, why does the code snippet in the book say "character"?**

I also noticed that the function signature is `basic_ostream& seekp( pos_type pos );` (see [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)), but I can't find an explanation of whether `pos_type` refers to a character or a byte.

The reference on [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/) also seems to define position in terms of characters (emphasis added):

> Sets the position where the next **character** is to be inserted into the output stream.

As does the following [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/lcezap/comment/gm0mqh3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) on a Reddit thread (emphasis added):

> A streampos IS NOT an integer, **it's not some byte position in a stream. It represents a character position in the stream,** and the type holds some stream state information for the purpose of code conversion and character position.

But this seems to contradict what I see in my example, where `fs.seekp(1)` seems to overwrite byte 1 (the 2nd byte).

Comment: This is partially platform-dependent; which one are you using?

Comment: WSL 2 with gcc 11.2.0.

Comment: `std::wfstream`s writes `wchar_t`s and they are 16 bits wide on windows and 32 on Linux. Not a very portable choice.

Comment: On the subject of portability, have a read about the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: I think "character" is `char` here rather than a code point or text element(i.e. what we see on the screen) in the concept of Unicode.

Comment: It's complicated, but my understanding is that `std::basic_ios<T>::pos_type` is a character position (and also not an integer) but `std::basic_ios<T>::off_type` is a byte offset. However `pos_type` has a non-explicit constructor from `off_type` which you are using in your test. It's up to the user to make sure that any `off_type` used in this way is a valid character position. In your case this was not true.

Comment: Incidentally `tellg` and `tellp` return  `std::basic_ios<T>::pos_type`, i.e. character positions.

Comment: @user51462 - The stream abstraction is designed to also work for systems with multi-byte non-unicode character sets, possibly using shift-state codes (in which case `streampos` might hold the state). And for systems where `char` holds more than 8 bits. None of this is visible on your Linux system. I wouldn't go too deep down this rabbit hole!

Comment: What was in `wide.txt` initially?

Comment: @user51462 If none of the answers answers your question, please clarify the problem so that we can improve our answers.

Comment: @PaulSanders, just a single wide character as shown in my post (above the **test.cpp** snippet).

Comment: Thank you @john, I think this clarifies it. So, when I pass an `int` to `seekp()` the non-explicit constructor is invoked, which returns a byte offset instead of a character position, is this correct? I'm also not sure how I could have obtained the correct character position programmatically. If you would consider posting your comment as an answer explaining this, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: The other way around, the integer is a byte offset and a character position is constructed from it. Because the byte offset of 1 is not a valid character position you get into trouble. The character position type is actually called [std::streampos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/fpos). You can do arithmetic on a `streampos` but only using byte offsets, which is another way of saying that you cannot know where the characters begin and end in your file without actually reading the file. There are no shortcuts in the case where a characters are encoded by a variable number of bytes.

Comment: @user51462 OK, it's really simple then.  std::fstream assumes that a character is one byte wide.  But you have (almost certainly) UTF-8 characters in your file and they can be more than one byte wide, so when you plonked something over the middle character of what looks like a 3-byte sequence, you broke it.

Comment: @PaulSanders: not quite. `std::basic_istream<char32_t>` assumes that characters are `sizeof(char32_t)~4` bytes wide, and `std::basic_istream<char>` assumes that characters are `sizeof(char)=1` bytes wide.

Comment: @MooingDuck But `std::fstream` == `std::basic_fstream<char>`, no?

Comment: @PaulSanders: oh, you're right. I failed to notice that you specified `std::fstream` specifically.

Answer (score 3):

`seekg()` and `seekp` operate on [code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Terminology) which are often referred to as "characters" in C++ although the latter term is pretty overloaded and may mean other things. They definitely don't operate on bytes which is easy to see if you consider that for wide streams the buffer elements have type `wchar_t`.

Quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf:

> The controlled character sequence (buffer) is an array of `CharT` which, at all times, represents a subsequence, or a "window" into the associated character sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> Do `seekg()` and `seekp()` operate on characters or bytes?

In the context of the `seek*` functions, they are the same thing - and it has only a very loose relation to visible (or invisible) characters in [graphemes, grapheme-like units or symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)).

For encodings, like UTF8, stepping *"a character"* will need clarification. A `seek*` character does not take code points into consideration, so stepping one `seek*`-character may position the r/w pointer somewhere inside a 4 octet long unicode character and reading or writing from/to there may result in an invalid codepoint - or some unexpected grapheme.

Answer (score 0):

> Do `seekg()` and `seekp()` operate on characters or bytes?

Both?

> why does the code snippet in the book say "character"?

`char` is a character. It represents one byte. In this context, they are the same.

There is also `wfstream`. It operates on *wide* characters. These characters take multiple bytes encoded in one `wchar_t` type.

> whether pos_type refers to a character or a byte.

This all is an abstraction. It depends on what the stream refers to. In case of `fstream` a character is one `char` which is one byte. In case of `wfstream` a character has `sizeof(wchar_t)` bytes. In case of my imaginary `typedef basic_ios<__uint128_t> my_super_stream_with_16_bytes_characters;` a character has 16 bytes.

> contradict what I see in my example, where fs.seekp(1) seems to overwrite byte 1

No, just `fs` *in this case* refers to a stream where one character represents one byte (on your operating system on your implementation).